# c# how to increment id for each instance of class automatically

Tags: c#, object, constructor

A user inserts KID NAME, the code instantiate an object and add it to list of objects.
How to give each object a unique number automatically starting at 1, such that first KID(object) gets number 1, second KID gets number 2 etc.
I tried something like this but the result is "stackoverflow".
How would the class should be?

```
class Kid
    {
        public string KidName{ get; set; }
        private static int Number { get; set; }
        public int KidNumber { get; set; }
        
        public Kid (string name)
        {
            this.KidName = name;
            Number++;
            this.KidNumber = Number;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The approach seems ok at first sight, as long as you don't deal with multithreading (using such static property is not thread-safe, but won't lead to a `StackOverflowException`).  You are probably recursively instantiating or calling indefinitely elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Please show us the code where you instantiate your class.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works successfully on my device.
Maybe you have an 'stackoverflow' for other reasons?

If you need only to identify Kid class, the alternative way is to use Guid:

```
class Kid
{
    public string KidName { get; set; }
    public Guid KidNumber { get; set; }

    public Kid(string name)
    {
        this.KidName = name;
        this.KidNumber = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Better" is a matter of interpretation.  It is for example MUCH slower to generate (there have also been reports of performance being even worse on non-Windows platforms.) and not very good if you want a human-readable ID, and takes up much more space.  So it depends on what you want to achieve as to if this is "better" or not.  "Alternative" would be a better description.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your example can induce a `StackOverflowException`. Stackoverflows occur when you repeatedly call the same method recursively either directly or indirectly (by way of an intermediate) or when you have an instance-level field of the same type as the instance itself (a special case of the former). You don't exhibit either case in your example so it must be due to something else *external* to the code you've shown. The most your code *could* potentially exhibit is an `OverflowException` [if you were in a `checked` context](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxAgrgOyQExAagB8ABAJgEYBYAKGIAYACY8gOgBUALBOCHAS0wBzANw0ydGmNIMA0nxw0A3jQaqGABwR8AbhHhNyANgYCYDAMIB7LPAQNFDQXBjCGUZ64C+DALwnMMCwAshAAHgBqEAA26HCi1GpMAMwGjHI4AHIQYHD2jh5uBZ4qasQpprLyGehgwIh5Ti6FTcUJaiWqZZU4ABTMjJjZcACUHfZjiTAcfFAs6Vk5vgyDOfGJk9Oz8zV1dn4Axhxw+wDWcL1WNoj4+MNraq2tUinKbZ2k0q/rarp2oUuYOAAd26PQARGC7hN2m8GI8gA===).

That said, your approach is OK at first glance with the obvious pitfall that it is not thread-safe. Two instance could in theory end up with the same `KidNumber`. You can fix *that* by making use of the `Interlocked` class:

```
using System.Threading;

class Kid
{
    private static int _counter;
    public string KidName { get; set; }
    public int KidNumber { get; set; }
    
    public Kid(string name)
    {
        this.KidName = name;
        this.KidNumber = Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter);
    }
}
```

Like `++` in an `unchecked` context, this handles the case of overflow; once you hit `int.MaxValue`, if will automatically wrap to `int.MinValue`. If you don't want negative IDs you'll have to handle that seperately.